# OpenVPN access server configuration is not added in client.ovpn file

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn, google-authenticator

I have set up an OpenVPN access server on an AWS EC2 instance. A domain name is associated with its Elastic IP and also configured SSL certificates. Also, enabled Google Authenticator MFA using Admin UI. Then created a user called ***testuser***. Then, I have logged in to client UI and setup MFA with Google Authenticator and then downloaded the user-locked profile ***(client.ovpn)*** as I'm using Ubuntu OS.

When I try to connect to VPN using the command: `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn`. It is asking only the username and password, not the MFA code. And it is failing with the given error:

```
Tue Jun 16 12:29:07 2020 [OpenVPN Server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]X.X.X.X:1194
Tue Jun 16 12:29:08 2020 SENT CONTROL [OpenVPN Server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Tue Jun 16 12:29:08 2020 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED,CRV1:R,E:PG_fTHWyc/CA7Xs7nA:dGVzjoVzZXI=:Enter Authenticator Code
Tue Jun 16 12:29:08 2020 SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
```

When I looked at the client.ovpn file with a working MFA config that I previously had, the given line is missing:

```
static-challenge "Enter Google Authenticator Code" 1
```

which means, that MFA configuration is not added to client config file. When I added this line on my file, the VPN starts working any issues.

So, how can I make this enable by default when a new user is created? Is there any other setting that I need to modify in Admin UI for this to be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue on a new install using the AWS provided package. Couldn't find a solution for getting the line auto added to the ovpn file. However, did discover its only a problem when using the older version of the client app. After upgrading to a new version direct from the new server (works alongside the old one) then the line isn't needed and it prompted for the 2fa code without issue.